# Andengine synchronization between animation

Tags: android, animation, synchronization, andengine

I am developing an Android game using **Andengine**, which is a **casino game - Roulette** (You can see an example [here](http://www.rouletteedu.com/american-roulette.php)).

In my game, instead of numbers, there are items on the roulette table. Therefore, when the roulette table rotates, the items also rotate along.

My problem is that, the items were rotated by using **PathModifier**, so it I could decide the total time for each round. However, the roulette table is an **AnimatedSprite**, and I only could decide the frame's duration, not the total time. Therefore, even though I calculated equal times for them, they were not synchronized with each other. Please give me a solution for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, I have found out the reason why the items and the roulette table were not synchronized was that: the table was called **.animate()** multiple time to be reduced the velocity, and that function took a little amount of time which caused the delay.

I still don't know how to solve that problem. I have thought of adding **DelayModifier** to the items so slow down them, but couldn't determine how long the delay is.